# What is the different between stringvariable != NullValue.String and !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringvariable) in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

Is there any different between stringvariable != NullValue.String and !string.IsNullOrEmpty(stringvariable) in asp.net ? then which is best ?

Answer (score 1):

The first tests that the string isn't "".

As strings can be `null` (because they are actually references) this test could fail.

By using [`IsNullOrEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorempty.aspx) you are wrapping:

```
if (string != null && string.Length > 0)
```

in one test.

Answer (score 1):

IsNullOrEmpty is implemented like:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return (value.Length == 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

So it checks both an empty string, and a null string. (Where is NullValue.String defined, I cannot seem to find a reference to it in any docs, but I assume it's eiter String.Empty or "null", so your first check only checks for one of these conditions.)

.Net4 has a new function called `IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)` which also returns true if the string contains only white space.